# Upgrading ng-jhipster Library for Compatibility with Angular 16.2.0

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am working on an Angular application that relies on the ng-jhipster library, specifically version 0.16.0. Here's the relevant section from the package.json of ng-jhipster:

```
{
  "name": "ng-jhipster",
  "description": "A Jhipster util library for Angular",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "jhipster",
    "angular",
    "angular2"
  ],
  "author": "Deepu KS",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://www.jhipster.tech",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0 || ^7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2 || ^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1 || ^0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.21",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.3",
    "@types/node": "13.13.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^2.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.30.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-jhipster": "0.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "husky": "4.2.5",
    "jest": "26.1.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.2.1",
    "lint-staged": "9.2.3",
    "ng-packagr": "^10.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "tsickle": "0.36.0",
    "tslint": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.9.5",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
  },
  "version": "0.16.0",
  "lint-staged": {
    "{,src/**/}*.{md,json,ts,html}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "cleanup": "rimraf dist/*",
    "format": "prettier --write \"{,src/**/}*.{md,json,ts,html}\"",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "test": "npm run lint && jest --config tests/jest.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "build": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.prod.json",
    "build:dev": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.dev.json --watch",
    "release": "git push && git push --tags && npm publish dist/",
    "clean-release": "npm run cleanup && npm run build && npm run release",
    "release:patch": "npm test && npm version patch -a -m \"Update to %s\" && npm run clean-release",
    "release:minor": "npm test && npm version minor -a -m \"Update to %s\" && npm run clean-release",
    "release:major": "npm test && npm version major -a -m \"Update to %s\" && npm run clean-release"
  }
}
```

The challenge is that my Angular application needs to be upgraded to the latest version, 16.2.0. However, ng-jhipster hasn't been updated for roughly 4 years and currently supports Angular up to version 10.0.0.

Given this scenario, what would be the recommended steps or best practices to upgrade ng-jhipster to be compatible with Angular 16.2.0? Any insights or experiences related to this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The JHipster Angular lib is now a part of generated projects, you can see it in action in [sample app](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app) in different folders like `src/main/webapp/app/shared`.

So you have 4 alternatives :

1. You use new jhipster v8 classes, copy them from a generated project to your project and adapt your project (code, build process)
2. You clone the git repo of ng-jhipster library to fork it, adapt it to latest version of Angular and other deps and build library by yourself.
3. A variant of #2 : you import ng-jhipster lib  0.16.0 source into your own project if you don't want to manage a library and don't care about change history
4. Last alternative that should work only for trivial projects : you generate a new project and import your custom code in to it.

I omitted `jhipster upgrade` alternative because it might not work if you are far behind JHipster current version (v8).

Personally, I did follow option #3 3 months after I initially generated our project, strategy was to cut dependency on JHipster as soon as project is mature enough and I never regret it. It was 2 years ago.

Another thing to consider is frontend build: starting from JHipster 7, it uses Angular CLI while before it was using a custom webpack configuration. So you might have to provision some time too to migrate your build to Angular CLI.

Comment: Currently using Approach #3 A variant of #2 : you import ng-jhipster lib 0.16.0 source into your own project if you don't want to manage a library and don't care about change history