# Angular 16.2.0 with TypeScript 5.1.6: Unexpected value 'NgJhipsterModule' imported error

Tags: angular, jhipster

I'm using "@angular/core": "^16.2.0", "typescript": "5.1.6", and "ng-jhipster": "0.16.0" in my Angular project. When trying to run the project, I encounter the following error:

```
app.main.ts:14 Error: Unexpected value 'NgJhipsterModule' imported by the module 'TechAppModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.
...
```

**Here's the relevant part of my app.module.ts:**

```
import { JhiEventManager, NgJhipsterModule } from 'ng-jhipster';

...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
...
        NgJhipsterModule.forRoot({
            alertAsToast: false,
            i18nEnabled: true,
            defaultI18nLang: 'en'
        }),
...
    ],
    declarations: [
...
    ],
    providers: [
        ...,
        DialogService,
        {
            provide: NgbDateParserFormatter,
            useClass: NgbDateCustomParserFormatter
        }
    ],
    exports: [...],
    bootstrap: [JhiMainComponent]
})
export class TechAppModule {}
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can guide me on how to resolve this? I suspect there might be some incompatibility or a missing configuration.

Answer (score 3):

ng-jhipster has [been merged](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/12909) into the [generator-jhipster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster).

As you can see the [repo is now read only](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster) since 2021.

You should probably take a look at their [demo app](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this library is outdated and it also has outdated dependencies. The last publish was 3 years ago, which I highly suspect it is not compatible with angular 16.

Comment: You are correct, Its an issue with incompatible ng-jhipster - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76919544/upgrading-ng-jhipster-library-for-compatibility-with-angular-16-2-0